# How to emulate a UIPickerView using Quartz 2D in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I need to create a spinner like UIPickerView using Quartz 2D.

How to scroll a list of images repeatedly like a spinner wheel ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the UIPickerView?  You can have custom rows, including images.

Comment: Coz UIPickerView could be not set to spin automatically for certain time interval. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Not directly, but you can tell it to select a specific row with animation - do that in a loop and it may be able to spin as long as you like.